# Skipping every two rows in gnuplot

Tags: syntax, gnuplot

I have a data file of the form

```
x1 x2 x3 x4


y1 y2 y3 y4


z1 z2 z3 z4
```

that is, after every row of data there is two empty lines. How to use the `every` command in gnuplot to ignore these lines when plotting the data? (otherwise it seems like gnuplot won't plot anything because of these spaces between the data rows)

```
 plot 'data.dat' every XXX u 1:2 ....
```

A simple question and I think the every command is the gnuplot command for this but I found it confusing so can't quite get the syntax right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to confirm: is your data really in rows instead on columns? Usually the first _column_ would by x, the second _column_ y, and the third _column_ z. What do you actually want to plot? The first column vs. the second or the first row vs. the second row? Which plotting style? points, lines, lines points or others...?

Comment: @theozh Thanks, yes I want to plot the first column vs. the second column. Excuse the confusing notation. I will use smooth bezier to put a curve through the points. All I was trying to work out is how to use `every` command to ignore the empty rows beween data rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, gnuplot will disconnect plotted lines if there is one or several empty lines in data. So, you wouldn't be able to plot your data `with lines` because there is nothing to connect. However, using `with points` you would see the datapoints. Apparently, `smooth` also "doesn't like" (double)emtpy lines. So, it boils down to: how can I remove the empty lines? One possible way would be to plot the data into a table (here: `$Data2`) and then plot this table using the option `smooth bezier`.

**Code:**

```
### remove emtpy lines for smooth
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   2   3


2   5   1


3   5   2


4   4   4


5   8   3


6   9   1
EOD

set table $Data2
    plot $Data u 1:2:3 w table
unset table

set key top left

plot $Data w p pt 7 ti "Data with double empty lines", \
     $Data2 u 1:2 smooth bezier w l lc "red" ti "smooth bezier"
### end of code
```

**Addition:** (after clarifications in comments)

**Code:** (if you have a file `'data.dat'` instead of inline data `$Data`)

```
### remove emtpy lines for smooth
reset session

FILE = 'data.dat'

set table $Data2
    plot FILE u 1:2:3 w table
unset table

set key top left

plot FILE w p pt 7 ti "Data with double empty lines", \
     $Data2 u 1:2 smooth bezier w l lc "red" ti "smooth bezier"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder, is it not possible with the every command in gnuplot?

Comment: Check `help every`. Documentation says: `every{<point_incr>}{:{<block_incr>}{:{<start_point>}{:{<start_block>}{:{<end_point>}{:<end_block>}}}}}` This is for selecting rows within a (sub)datablock separated by single empty lines. Furthermore, blocks of data which is separated by two empty lines can be selected by `index` (check `help index`). So, I don't see how you could solve your question with `every`.

Comment: thanks. Yes I see now that `index` is the relevant one. I thought `plot 'data.dat' index 0::1 u 1:2 ls 1 notitle,\ ` would have worked but it seems not. I understood `index 0::1` to mean start at index 0 and plot every index subsequent to that (where an index is separated by a pair of empty lines). I have also tried `index 0::2` and `index 0::3` but also didn't work. Do you know how to use this command here properly?

Comment: @CAF `plot 'data.dat' index 0::1 u 1:2` is what gnuplot would do anyway with `plot 'data.dat' u 1:2`. Plot all (sub)blocks starting from 0 until end with step 1. So, I would guess there is no solution with `index` and `every`, because the datapoints will still be separated by two empty lines.

Comment: It is very surprising to me that there could possibly be no solution using index and every for such a naively simple question! :) Ok, in such a case, how can your answer  be adapted where the data are in a separate file `data.dat` ?

Comment: @CAF Maybe there is a solution with `index` and `every` (I doubt), but which I am not aware of. What do you mean with data in different files? x,y, and z in different files? Please clarify and modify your original question or post a new question if you want to have something different what you asked here.

Comment: oh sorry I had meant when all the data are in another file. As far as I can tell from your answer, you have done everything within one script and I was wondering how to adapt your answer when the three columns of data are in a file data.dat.

Comment: simply skip the `$Data <<EOD ... EOD` part and in the two plot commands replace `$Data` with `'data.dat'`, but leave the two `$Data2` as is. Does this answer your question?